# AngularJS show element onScroll function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is our javascript:

```
window.onscroll=function(){scrollShow()};
    function scrollShow(){
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop>150){
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display="block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display="none";
        }
    }
```

How to make the same function in AngularJS?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a directive

```
<button id='myBtn' scroll-show></div>

app.directive('scrollShow', [function() {
  return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.on('scroll', function (e) {
        if(....) {
            element.hide();
        } else {
            element.show();
        }
      });
    })
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a directive. You can attach created directive to your html tag/component/directive and attach event listener to window there. You can try this approach.

```js
angular.module('myModule', [])

.directive('myScrollShowDirective', ['$window', function($window) {

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var format,
        timeoutId;
    // or attach event in jquery style    
    $window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollShow);


    function scrollShow(){
        if ($window.document.documentElement.scrollTop>150){
            element.style.display="block";
        } else {
            element.style.display="none";
        }
    }

    element.on('$destroy', function() {
      $window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollShow);
    });

  }

  return {
    link: link
  };
}]);
```